# Read a file in Android Studio with no Activity

Tags: java, android

Need to read a file in, with Android Studio with no Activity. Just trying to use the AS as a regular Java Compiler and IDE. The file was not found. How does one opens a file in AS with no Activity?

Searched around and saw that maybe I should be using AssetManager. However the getAsset() is unrecognized. Saw some suggestions to create a constructor with Context and use the context. That did not work either.

```
public class MyJavaTest  {

Context ctx;

//public MyJavaTest(Context ctx) {
//    this.ctx = ctx;
//}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //AssetManager asm = mcx.getResources().getAssets();
    String inFile = "com/zodllc/javatest/input1.txt";
```

Comment: "How does one opens a file in AS with no Activity?" -- how are you planning on running this code?

Comment: Android Studio is just extension of IntelliJ Idea, which You should use instead for pure java projects. In Studio You'll just need to keep jumping thru hoops to ignore/disable a lot of android specific functionality.

Comment: there is a "community edition" of [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)... while I fail to see the relation to Android Java here, with the typical Java method `public static void main`... and there won't be any `Context` or `Resources` available, because this is specific to Android Java. my best guess would be using a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services).

Comment: This question is particular to Android Studio!